# Htaccess Virtual Subdomain not work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I Use Htaccess File to RewriteRule My Website Subdomains to relative files on my site.
For example:

`http://articles.mysite.com -->  http://mysite.com/articles`
I write this code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mysite.*
RewriteRule ^$ ./%1 [L]
```

But When i Want Use This :

`http://articles.mysite.com/some/some  --> http://mysite.com/articles/some/some`

Above code doesn't work properly and redirect me to 404 NotFound Page

Note: In another place of my .htaccess file i have `RewriteRule ^some/(.*)$ ./some.php?id=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

and add a condition to prevent looping:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
```

So you have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mysite.*
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @EbadGhafoory it will **only** work if the `/articles/some/some` is a file or directory, otherwise nothing is rewritten and a 404 error will occur.

Comment: i have this in my htaccess : `RewriteRule ^some/(.*)$ ./some.php?id=$1 [L]`